# Mantener parametros del request en un queue import de Laravel excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Como lo indico en el titulo necesito poder importar un cvs pero hay cierto parámetros que se obtienen de un formulario en cual no logro recuperar cuando se importa dicho archivo, dichos campos provienen de lo antes mencionado y los paso como variables en el construct de la class del importador dejo el código y me indique que estoy haciendo mal ya que dichos parámetro siempre pasan como null

**Controllador**

```
(new MayorImport($request->input('cliente_id'), $request->input('soft_contable')))->queue($file, 'public');
```

Nota: El archivo se sube y se ejecuta en segundo plano por lo que creo que el  request no funciona al iniciar el comando `php artisan queue:work`

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\CuentaContabilidad;
use App\Mayor;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class MayorImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    use Importable;

    protected $cliente_id;
    protected $soft_contable;

    public function __construct($cliente_id, $soft_contable)
    {
        $this->cliente_id = $cliente_id;
        $this->soft_contable = $soft_contable;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        if (!CuentaContabilidad::where('codigo', $row['cuenta'])->where('cliente_id', $this->cliente_id)->exists()) {
            $centro_costo = CuentaContabilidad::create([
                'rut_cliente' => $row['rut_empresa'],
                'cliente_id' => $this->cliente_id,
                'codigo' => $row['cuenta'],
                'soft_contable' => Session::get('soft_contable'),
                'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
            ]);
            return new Mayor([
                'cliente_id' => Session::get('cliente_id'),
                'periodo' => $row['periodo'],
                'cuenta_id' => $centro_costo->id,
                'comp_nro' => $row['comprobante'],
                'comp_tipo' => $row['tipo'],
                'valor_cargo' => $row['debe'],
                'valor_abono' => $row['haber'],
                'cc_nom' => $row['centro_costo'],
                'rut' => $row['rut'],
            ]);

        }

    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ";",
        ];
    }
}
```

Al hacer un `dd($this->cliente_id)` este devuelve un null en la consola

```
[2021-09-22 01:04:09][2] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\ReadChunk
null
```

Comment: no deberia molestar pero alguna vez me paso, intenta colocando los atributos publicos en la clase

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: te funciono con public?

Comment: Si me funciono lo probé ayer

Comment: ok, voy a colocar la respuesta para que la marques por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes colocar los atributos publicos en el archivo, asi

```
 <?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\CuentaContabilidad;
use App\Mayor;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class MayorImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    use Importable;

    public $cliente_id;
    public $soft_contable;

    public function __construct($cliente_id, $soft_contable)
    {
        $this->cliente_id = $cliente_id;
        $this->soft_contable = $soft_contable;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        if (!CuentaContabilidad::where('codigo', $row['cuenta'])->where('cliente_id', $this->cliente_id)->exists()) {
            $centro_costo = CuentaContabilidad::create([
                'rut_cliente' => $row['rut_empresa'],
                'cliente_id' => $this->cliente_id,
                'codigo' => $row['cuenta'],
                'soft_contable' => Session::get('soft_contable'),
                'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
            ]);
            return new Mayor([
                'cliente_id' => Session::get('cliente_id'),
                'periodo' => $row['periodo'],
                'cuenta_id' => $centro_costo->id,
                'comp_nro' => $row['comprobante'],
                'comp_tipo' => $row['tipo'],
                'valor_cargo' => $row['debe'],
                'valor_abono' => $row['haber'],
                'cc_nom' => $row['centro_costo'],
                'rut' => $row['rut'],
            ]);

        }

    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ";",
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo por compartir sus conocimientos